# Lifting of a ucp map with values in a von Neumann algebra ultraproduct of matrix algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $u:A \to \prod_{\mathcal U} M_n$ be a unital completely positive map (ucp) from a unital separable $C^*$algebra into the von Neumann algebra ultraprodut $\prod_{\mathcal U} M_n$.

Here $\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ and $\prod_{\mathcal U} M_n$ is the quotient of $B=\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}, x_n \in M_n(\mathbb C) , \sup_n \|x_n\|<\infty\}$ by the ideal $I_{\mathcal U}=\{(x_n)_n, \lim_{\mathcal U} Tr(x_n^* x_n)/n = 0\}$.

> Does there exist a ucp lifting of $u$, i.e. a sequence $u_n:A \to M_n(\mathbb C)$ of ucp maps such that $u=q \circ (u_n)$, where $q:B\to B/I_{\mathcal U}$ is the quotient map?

If not, is $u$ locally liftable? That is: given a finite dimensional operator system $E\subset A$ (= a subspace $E$ of $A$ containing $1$ and stable under $a \mapsto a^*$), does there exist a ucp lifting of the restriction of $u$ to $E$?

Some comments: as in [my related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68367/), I know that the answer is no in general if one replaces the von Neumann algebra ultraproduct by the $C^*$-algebra ultraproduct. But I hope that again, the situation might be much simpler in the von Neumann algebra setting. (I even have the feeling that I have known the answer to this question, but that I have forgotten it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, in general there is no lifting. A lifting exists if the $C^{\ast}$-algebra has the so-called lifting property (LP), and local liftings exist if it has the local lifting property (LLP).

I constructed in

Andreas Thom, *Examples of hyperlinear groups without factorization property*, Groups Geom. Dyn. 4, no. 1 (2010) 195-208.

an example of a group $G$, such that the universal group $C^{\ast}$-algebra of $G$ does not have the LLP. The idea is that $G$ is hyperlinear, but cannot have Kirchberg's factorization property. The hyperlinearity is shown by a concrete construction of micro-states, Kirchberg's factorization property has to fail since $G$ has property (T), but is not residually finite. Note that Kirchberg showed that Kazhdan groups with factorization property are residually finite. See also

Narutaka Ozawa, *About the QWEP conjecture*, Internat. J. Math. 15 (2004), no. 5, 501–
530.

where all these concepts are explained.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for this answer. I was aware of Ozawa's survey, and I have read your paper during my phd thesis. The point that I seem to be missing is why the lack of LP (or LLP) for $A$ is necessarily witnessed by a ucp map with values in $\prod_{\mathcal U} M_n$ (in my understanding if $A$ does not have the (L)LP, there exists a C*algebra B with an ideal $J$ and a ucp map $A\to B/J$ without (local) lifting).

Comment: Mikael, the way I show that the universal group $C^{\ast}$-algebra does not have LLP is precisely by showing that there are no local lifts from some matrix ultraproduct.

Comment: Ok, everything is clear now. I had completely forgotten Kirchberg's factorization property, but it was exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: Andreas, are there any other examples of groups (except Abel's type groups from your paper) that are known to fail LLP?

Comment: Any hyperlinear, non-residually finite, Kazhdan group. There are only few examples, I guess.