# Almost commuting unitary matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Suppose that $A_1,\dots, A_k$ are unitary matrices such that any two of them can be approximated by commuting unitary matrices. i.e. for any $i$ and $j$, there are unitary matrices $A_i'$ and $A_j'$ such that $\|A_i-A_i'\|<\varepsilon$, $\|A_j-A_j'\|<\varepsilon$ and $A_i'A_j'=A_j'A_i'$. Can we find unitary matrices $X_1,\dots,X_k$ such that any two of them commute and $\|X_i-A_i\|<O(\varepsilon)$ for all $i$?
What if any three (or small number) of them can be simultaneously approximated by commuting unitary matrices?

Here the matrix norm could be any unitary invariant norm. I'm specially interested in the operator norm and Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

Comment: Here's a thought. Suppose we're in a vector space $V$ over an algebraically closed field, and each of the operators $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ has distinct eigenvalues. Make $\varepsilon$ small enough that the operators in the $\varepsilon$-ball around each $A_i$ also have distinct eigenvalues. That means any operator $\varepsilon$-near one of the $A_i$ decomposes $V$ into eigenlines.

Comment: Now, suppose we can find commuting operators $A_i'$ and $A_j'$ within $\varepsilon$ of $A_i$ and $A_j$ respectively. Since $A_i'$ and $A_j'$ commute, they have the same eigenlines $L_1, \ldots, L_n$. If $\varepsilon$ is small enough, I think the eigenlines of $A_i$ and $A_j$ should have to be near $L_1, \ldots, L_n$, and therefore near each other. In other words, for small enough $\varepsilon$, your commutative approximation condition implies that the eigenlines of the operators $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ almost match.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're saying that you know that there exists a solution and the question is how to find it? Or am I misunderstanding (because Mikael's answer says "no" for one instance...).

Comment: The question is that you know any two (or three or small number) of them can be approximated simultaneously by commuting unitary matrices and the question is to approximate all of them together (with a good bound such as $c\varepsilon$) with commuting unitary matrices. As I understand Miakel's answer is no for approximately commuting Hermitian matrices and doesn't apply here.

Comment: You can use Cayley transform to pass between hermitian and unitary matrices. This preserves commutativity, but of course distorts the norm. (Cayley transform is only a birational map, it is undefined at unitary matrices with eigenvalue $-1$.)

Comment: Well as I understand two cases of unitary and self-adjoint matrices are different.

For example there are two unitary matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $||[A,B]||_{op}$ is small but they can't be approximated with commuting unitary matrices.
http://mtm.ufsc.br/~exel/papers/asympt.pdf

But the answer to the other case is yes for any pair of almost commuting matrices and it is called Huaxin Lin's Theorem
http://www.math.ku.dk/~rordam/manus/short.pdf

Comment: Are you fixing the order $n$ of the matrices? As I understand it, it is crucial in the question linked by Mikael de la Salle that the bound be uniform in $n$.

Comment: No! $n$ can be very large. For example Lev Glebsky obtains a bound that doesn't depend on $n$ for any pair of matrices in the case that norm is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3082v1.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit** Now this answers the first question for the operator norm and the normalized Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

The answer depends on the norm you are considering. The answer is no for the operator norm, but is yes for the normalized Hilbert-Schmidt norm (at least if you replace $O(\varepsilon)$ by $o(1)$, see the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68367/are-almost-commuting-hermitian-matrices-close-to-commuting-matrices-in-the-2-no)).

Here are some details on the counterexample for the operator norm.

1. By a theorem of Lin (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68367/are-almost-commuting-hermitian-matrices-close-to-commuting-matrices-in-the-2-no)), for a pair of self-adjoint matrices of norm less than $1$, they approximately commute if and only if they can be approximated by commuting matrices.
2. Voiculescu proved that the preceding does not hold for triples of  self-adjoint matrices of norm less than $1$ (see the link I gave [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68367/are-almost-commuting-hermitian-matrices-close-to-commuting-matrices-in-the-2-no), or the references in the paper by Exel and Loring given in the comments).

1+2 imply that there is a sequence of triples $A_1^n,A_2^n,A_3^n$ of matrices of norm less than $1$ which are pairwise close to (self-adjoint) commuting matrices, but whose distance to the triples of commuting matrices is bounded below.

3. By continuity of the functional calculus and the fact that $t \in [-2,2] \mapsto e^{it}$ is a homeomorphism on its image, this implies that the unitary matrices $(e^{i A_1^n}, e^{i A_1^n},e^{i A_1^n})$ are pairwise close
   to pairs of commuting unitaries, but are at positive distance from triples of commuting unitaries. This is what you were looking for.

Comment: Is there any counterexample for $k=3$ in the case that matrices are unitary?

Comment: Can I check that you are talking about the same question? Here the assumption is not that any two of the matrices approximately commute, but rather the stronger assumption that any two of the matrices can be approximated by a pair of commuting matrices. I can't seem to track down a counterexample to this in the literature.

Comment: Oops, you are both right, I missed the word unitary in the question. The references give a counterexample for self-adjoint matrices (I will expand my answer to make this precise). I have no idea what the answer is for unitary matrices.

Comment: Well, it seems that the unitary version of the question also has a negative answer by considering, for a self adjoint matrix $A $, the unitary $e^{iA/10} $.